# Function as array value a element

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a function with the data I received from json and the student name and surname. I don't have any problems when there is only one student number, but if there are two students in the incoming data, the student number comes in the array. What should I do in this case?

```
if($adi =="Turkce")
{
    $tip = "DuzMantik";
    $values = array();
    foreach($olan->selections as $solan){

        $og_numarasi = $solan->description;
        $notum = $solan->note;

        $ogrneci_adi = ogrenciadial($yil,$hafta,$og_numarasi);
        $values[] = array("tur"=>$og_numarasi,"tid"=>$ogrneci_adi,"not"=>$notum);
    }

    $array2 = array(
        "tip" => $tip,
        "id" => 1,
        "notlar" => $values,
    );

    array_push($kod, $array2);
}

ogrenciadial($yil,$hafta,$og_numarasi);



ogrenciadial(1998,5,?);
```

Comment: Which variable in the above code represents your student number?

Comment: Check if the variable is an array [is_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), if it is an array, take the first item.

Comment: Thanks in advance, the student number variable "$og_numarasi"

Comment: What does the JSON data look like when there are multiple students? Can you add an example?

Comment: I guess you have to check `if(is_array($og_numarasi))$og_numarasi=$og_numarasi[0];`.

Comment: @jeemusu when there are two students   description: "4,1",

Comment: @Yazan W Yusuf I need to get the name of both students from the function, how should I get the name of the two students?

Comment: so `$solan->description` isn't an array, but a comma delimited string?

Comment: @Jeemusu yes, how can I get the names of both students by function?

The function I wrote works like this. ogrenciadial($yil,$hafta,$og_numarasi);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to turn the comma delimited string into an array.

```
$og_numarasi = explode(',', $solan->description);
```

You can then loop through the `$og_numarasi` array to add each as a new entry into your `$values` array.

```
if($adi =="Turkce") {
    $tip = "DuzMantik";
    $values = array();

    foreach($olan->selections as $solan) {
        $og_numarasi = explode(',', $solan->description);

        $notum = $solan->note;
        foreach($og_numarasi as $number) {
            $ogrneci_adi = ogrenciadial($yil,$hafta,$number);
            $values[] = array("tur"=>$number,"tid"=>$ogrneci_adi,"not"=>$notum);
        }
    }


    $array2 = array(
        "tip" => $tip,
        "id" => 1,
        "notlar" => $values,
    );

    array_push($kod, $array2);
}
```